# Rust "Borrowed pointers" syntax

Tags: pointers, rust

Reading the [rust tutorial](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/guide-lifetimes.html) managed and owned pointers can be passed to a function requiring borrowed pointers as-is and are converted to borrowed pointers at compile time.

Why can't the stack variable be passed in the same way? What syntax or feature requires the explicit `&` operator to pass that one as opposed to the compiler automatically converting it?

```
struct Point {x: float, y: float}

let on_the_stack :  Point =  Point {x: 3.0, y: 4.0};
let managed_box  : @Point = @Point {x: 5.0, y: 1.0};
let owned_box    : ~Point = ~Point {x: 7.0, y: 9.0};

fn compute_distance(p1: &Point, p2: &Point) -> float {
    let x_d = p1.x - p2.x;
    let y_d = p1.y - p2.y;
    sqrt(x_d * x_d + y_d * y_d)
}

compute_distance(&on_the_stack, managed_box);
compute_distance(managed_box, owned_box);
```

Adding to the confusion is a quote from kibwen on ycombinator (I can't find the original quote but here's the quote of the quote)

> We’ll still have & and &mut, but those aren’t pointers, they’re references (it’s our own fault for calling them “borrowed pointers” in our documentation)

If `compute_distance` is taking references and the compiler converts pointers to references automatically why can't it do the same for values?

**Edit:** Since pnkfelix seems to know what he's talking about I'll copy some dialogue here for easier reading.

pnkfelix

> The designers of Rust decided to not follow the path of C++ in this respect. One side-effect of this decision is that when someone reading the code looks at an invocation like f(x, y) in Rust, one need not spend time wondering "wait, how does f take its arguments; if it mutates y, will I see that reflected in that after f returns? What about x?" etc.

J V

> I may be confused on the nature of references then. `@var` and `~var` in rust are pointers (Though they do behave more like references) - are C++ references simply pointers under the hood?
>
> In any case, I could apply the same logic to C with regards to code readability.
>
> Variables are either values or pointers (Where you simply pass the variable as you do in rust: `f(var)`) or are referenced in the function call (like you do in rust: `f(&var)`) - I would have thought the rust compiler would recognize the function signature and handle this automatically. I don't see the improvement over C or C++

pnkfelix

> One followup: this line that I wrote: "wait, how does f take its arguments; if it mutates y, will I see that reflected in that after f returns? What about x?" is somewhat facetious, since even a call like f(&x, y) would not be able to modify x; it would have to be f(&mut x, y). (and the declaration of x itself would have to be let mut x = ..., etc. – pnkfelix 1 hour ago
>
> 2nd followup: a reason why explicit &x may be more important in Rust than in C/C++ (rather than letting f(x,y) implicitly do the borrow &x), is because the borrow checker forces borrows to follow certain rules, and will refuse to compile code that does not conform. When you get an error from the borrow-checker, IMO it is a better user-experience if the compiler points to an expression of the form &x or &mut x in the source, rather that pointing to a function call and saying "there's an implicit borrow here." (That's subjective opinion, of course.) – pnkfelix 1 hour ago
>
> I saw that you had a follow-up note in your reply, but I don't understand the point you are making about applying "the same logic to C". If you mean C as opposed to C++, then you usually do have to explicitly take addresses of memory when invoking functions that expect pointers. If a function takes a `int**`, then someone needs to do `&E` where `E` is an l-value of type `int*`. That seems analogous to Rust to me. (The main exception to this that I recall offhand from C is function-pointers; you don't need to do `&f` to make a function pointer to `f`.) – pnkfelix 1 hour ago

J V

> *That seems analogous to Rust to me.* - exactly my point - from a readability point of view there's not much of an improvement over plain C. *because the borrow checker forces borrows to follow certain rules...rather that pointing to a function call and saying "there's an implicit borrow here."* Bingo - this is one of the underlying reasons I was looking for. If you find any other reasons for the manual cast feel free to add to your answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the intent is to make it clear to the reader when a copy of the struct is being made versus when a reference to the existing struct is being passed along. (more on this below.)

The managed-box and owned-box in the example listed are already references; they are just being temporarily converted from one kind of a reference (`@Point` and `~Point` respectively) into `&Point` references.  But they are both just references, nonetheless, and no copy is being made of the referenced storage.

---

It might well be the case that the Rust compiler *could* infer, based on the type signature of the function being called, when a reference needs to be created versus when the struct needs to be copied in.

Indeed, that's exactly what a C++ compiler does when it sees a call like `f(x, y)`: it needs to look at the signature of `f`, such as `f(A &a, B b)`, and from that determine: "Okay, I'll make a reference for the x argument (assuming it is of type A) and make a copy of the y argument (assuming it is of type B), since it is passed-by-value."

The designers of Rust decided to not follow the path of C++ in this respect.  One side-effect of this decision is that when someone reading the code looks at an invocation like `f(x, y)` in Rust, one need not spend time wondering "wait, how does `f` take its arguments; if it mutates `y`, will I see that reflected in that after `f` returns?  What about `x`?"  etc.

- (Of course, one still needs to reason about memory *reachable* from `x` and `y` via any mutable or owned references they themselves hold... but I digress.)

Comment: I may be confused on the nature of references then. `@var` and `~var` in rust are pointers (Though they do behave more like references) - are C++ references simply pointers under the hood?
In any case, I could apply the same logic to C with regards to code readability.
Variables are either values or pointers (Where you simply pass the variable as you do in rust: `f(var)`) or are referenced in the function call (like you do in rust: `f(&var)`) - I would have thought the rust compiler would recognize the function signature and handle this automatically. I don't see the improvement over C or C++

Comment: One followup: this line that I wrote: "wait, how does f take its arguments; if it mutates y, will I see that reflected in that after f returns? What about x?" is somewhat facetious, since even a call like `f(&x, y)` would not be able to modify `x`; it would have to be `f(&mut x, y)`.  (and the declaration of `x` itself would have to be `let mut x = ...`, etc.

Comment: 2nd followup: a reason why explicit `&x` may be more important in Rust than in C/C++ (rather than letting `f(x,y)` implicitly do the borrow `&x`), is because the borrow checker forces borrows to follow certain rules, and will refuse to compile code that does not conform.  When you get an error from the borrow-checker, IMO it is a better user-experience if the compiler points to an expression of the form `&x` or `&mut x` in the source, rather that pointing to a function call and saying "there's an implicit borrow here."  (That's subjective opinion, of course.)

Comment: I saw that you had a follow-up note in your reply, but I don't understand the point you are making about applying "the same logic to C".  If you mean C as opposed to C++, then you usually *do* have to explicitly take addresses of memory when invoking functions that expect pointers.  If a function takes a `int**`, then someone needs to do `&E` where `E` is an l-value of type `int*`.  That seems analogous to Rust to me.  (The main exception to this that I recall offhand from C is function-pointers; you don't need to do `&f` to make a function pointer to `f`.)

Comment: `That seems analogous to Rust to me.` - exactly my point - from a readability point of view there's not much of an improvement over plain C. `because the borrow checker forces borrows to follow certain rules...rather that pointing to a function call and saying "there's an implicit borrow here."` Bingo - this is one of the underlying reasons I was looking for. If you find any other reasons for the manual cast feel free to add to your answer!